# Dropdown button struggle

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu from my navbar when someone is hovering the button. Here's what I wrote:

```css
.navigation-bar {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid blue;   }

.navbutton {
    justify-content: flex-end; }

.navigation-bar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex; }

.navigation-bar a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 8px;
    padding-right: 10px; }

#logo {
    padding-left: 50px; }

.arrow {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
     }

.navigation-bar button {
    justify-content: flex-end; }

.wrapper-button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 60px;
    top: 30%; }

#navbutton {
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #3A79F6;
    color: #3A79F6;
    border-radius: 25px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px; } 

#navbutton:hover {
    background-color: #3A79F6;
    transition-delay: 0.4s;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer; }

.dropdown ul {
    display: inline; }

.test a{
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid blue; }


.test a:hover {
    display: inline;
    border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
    <div class="navigation-bar">
        <img src="images/image 18.png" id="logo" alt="seotag">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">functionality</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Explorer</a></li>
            <div class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#"> Souscriptions <img class="arrow" src="images/down.png" alt=""></a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="test"><a href="#">Test Dropdown 1</a></li>
                    <li class="test"><a href="#">Test Dropdown 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Templates</a></li>
            <li ><a href="#">Wix partners</a><img class="arrow" src="images/down.png" alt=""></li>
                
            <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Languages</a><img class="arrow" src="images/down.png" alt=""></li>
                
        </ul>
        <div class="wrapper-button">
        <button id="navbutton">Se Connecter</button>
```

I'm trying to display inline the elements of the dropdown list, then display none and only when someone is hovering the button to show the elements but for some reason it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
.dropdown ul{
  display: none;
}

.dropdown:hover ul{
   display: block; //or display: inline block
}`
```

Comment: Wow only because i was writing hover the wrong way holy f thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Drop-downs are always hard to style, I made a little example so you can see what you can do to make a element visible while hovering another element.

```css
/* Dropdown related styling */

.dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.has-dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.has-dropdown:hover .dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown a {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
  text-wrap: nowrap;
  background: #FFF;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  border: 1px solid black;
}


/* Other styling */

.navigation-bar {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.navbutton {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.navigation-bar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown ul {
  display: inline;
}

.navigation-bar a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

logo {
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.arrow {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}

.navigation-bar button {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.wrapper-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 60px;
  top: 30%;
}

navbutton {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #3A79F6;
  color: #3A79F6;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

navbutton:hover {
  background-color: #3A79F6;
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-bar">
  <img src="images/image 18.png" id="logo" alt="seotag">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">functionality</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Explorer</a></li>
    <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#"> Souscriptions <img class="arrow" src="images/down.png" alt=""></a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <ul>
          <li class="test"><a href="#">Test Dropdown 1</a></li>
          <li class="test"><a href="#">Test Dropdown 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Templates</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Wix partners</a><img class="arrow" src="images/down.png" alt=""></li>

    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Languages</a><img class="arrow" src="images/down.png" alt=""></li>

  </ul>
  <div class="wrapper-button">
    <button id="navbutton">Se Connecter</button>
  </div>
</div>
```